# Click if enabled current element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want create directive to check class of current element and if it is not disabled, invoke a function.

But it doesn't work, I can't see any errors.

```
app.directive("clickIfEnabled", ['$parse', '$rootScope', function ($parse, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($element, attr) {
            // We expose the powerful $event object on the scope that provides access to the Window,
            // etc. that isn't protected by the fast paths in $parse.  We explicitly request better
            // checks at the cost of speed since event handler expressions are not executed as
            // frequently as regular change detection.
            var eventname = "click-if-enabled";
            var fn = $parse(attr.attr[eventname], /* interceptorFn */ null, /* expensiveChecks */ true);
            return function ngEventHandler(scope, element) {
                element.on("click", function (event) {
                    var callback = function () {
                        fn(scope, { $event: event });
                    };
                    //if (forceAsyncEvents[eventName] && $rootScope.$$phase) {
                    //    scope.$evalAsync(callback);
                    //} else {
                        scope.$apply(callback);
                  //  }
                });
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SbrKj/116/
just should show alert("did something")

Comment: arguments of `link` are not in correct order...missing `scope`. I don't see where you are checking class. Seems like all you need is to put `element.on()` in a simple `if()` based on class . Create a demo

Comment: demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SbrKj/116/ just should show alert("did something")

Comment: Try this  http://jsfiddle.net/SbrKj/117/. There are numerous issues in your version. Wrong `link` arguments, `attr` properties are camelCase and your returned function never gets invoked